# moving files within a bucket in s3 *fast* using airflow

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-cli, airflow

I have a custom airflow operator which simply copies a list of s3 files within the same bucket

```
    for src, list in move_list:
        s3_hook.copy_object(
            source_bucket_key=src,
            dest_bucket_key=dest,
            source_bucket_name=self.bucket_name,
            dest_bucket_name=self.bucket_name
        )
```

And this is insanely slow ... takes about 8 minutes for about 800 files. Compared to when I run something like `aws s3 cp {src} {dest} --recursive` which is lightening fast.

Has anyone gone through this before? Is there a way to speed this up, or maybe is there some way to just use the cli instead?

Answer (score 0):

You can use BashOperator or PythonOperator to execute the CLI command. I don't think it is related to Airflow but to boto3, the AWS python library